# Ceph S3 ACLs Not Working When Using OIDC and STS Tokens

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph

I'm currently working with a Ceph S3 setup and using OIDC to generate STS tokens for authentication. However, I'm encountering a problem when trying to apply ACLs to users authenticated this way. The ACLs that I've assigned don't appear to be affecting the user permissions as they should.

The process I've been following is as follows:

I generate an STS token using OIDC.

I use the STS token for authentication with Ceph S3.

I assign specific ACLs to the users authenticated with these STS tokens.

According to the ACLs, users should have access only to specific resources and services. For example, if an ACL only grants read access, a user should not be able to write to a bucket, and vice versa.

However, what I'm finding is that the system is not honoring these ACLs. Users can either access more than their ACLs allow, or they can't access services or resources that they should be able to according to their ACLs.

I have triple-checked the ACLs and the authentication process to ensure everything is configured correctly, yet the issue remains. I'm beginning to think this might be an issue with the system itself or an unexpected interaction between OIDC, STS tokens, and ACLs.

Any guidance or advice to help resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.